# For Jmeter post request, how can I send multiple requests in body from CSV(already have JSON inside) file?

Tags: json, rest, csv, jmeter, http-post

I have a csv file and it has hundred record of JSON. I want to send JSON in body of JMETER post request one by one from CSV.

I tried this and I am getting desired results, but it is adding " " to every variable or data.for example: while sending this as a body

```
[
   {
      "id":"1232435",
      "ref":"88f000",
      "data":"5a344f",
      "number":"896751245"
   }
]
```

jmeeter is processing this body as
[image]

```
"[
   {
      ""id"":""1232435"",
      ""ref"":""88f000"",
      ""data"":""5a344f"",
      ""number"":""896751245""
   }
]"
```

I want it to process same as in csv file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSBgt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, double check your JSON file contents.

If I put the following line into CSV file:

```
[{"id":"1232435","ref":"88f000","data":"5a344f","number":"896751245"}]
```

it's being sent as it is without any extra quotation marks.

[image]

Also you have `dataa` in the CSV Data Set Config and `data` in the HTTP Request so it might be the case that you're not actually reading the file at all because given your current CSV Data Set Config setup you would get only first line of the file into the `data` variable to wit your request would look like `[`

So use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) to see whether the variable is correct and how it does look like. If there are still extra quotation marks they can be removed using [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup)

Comment: Can you please show me your csv file and CSV Data SET Config?
This is my POST data:
POST data:
"[{""id"":""1232435"",""ref"":""88f000"",""data"":""5a344f"",""number"":""896751245""}]"

[no cookies]

Comment: please find the link and let me know my mistakes
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XGHrJh9Eo2SM2kFOgoaByAhWxWyx_W0/view?usp=sharing
THIS WOULD REALLY HELP ME